# Magento Catalog Search not working properly 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

My code is perfect, i have tested on another database, but on current live server database i can't search any result in my portal. can you please help me which issue is occurring in database ? Thanks

Comment: Is the catalog search index update? Is there a error when you rebuild it? And which type of "code" do you mean, have you changed the Magento default search functionality?

Comment: catalog search index is re-indexed successfully. error is not showing just when i search any SKU i getting this message (Your search returns no results.) code mean my back-end coding-programming is working fine, no any issue is there.

Comment: do other search terms than SKU work? this could mean that the sku attribute is not searchable in your Magento

Comment: i have checked sku attribute, there sku is searchable.

Comment: You have make custom code for that?

Comment: No, i'm using default search.